# Select the last message between two users with Group and If statement coupled with Order by

Tags: php, mysqli

I am selecting the last message between two users of a chat system. However, though I am able to select it well, I am not able to order the message according to message that have not been read.

This is what my chat table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mychat_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `sent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `read_statu` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `to` (`to_id`),
  KEY `from` (`from_id`),
  KEY `direction` (`is_deleted`),
  KEY `read` (`read_statu`),
  KEY `sent` (`sent`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=58 ;
```

Now to select the last message between the two users I did this

```
$recup_id = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT MAX(`id`) AS id FROM mychat_table WHERE  (`from_id`='$id' OR `to_id`='$id') AND 

(is_deleted!='$id' AND is_deleted >=0) ORDER BY read_statu ASC GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id', `from_id`, `to_id`))    LIMIT 5  ") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

**Problem**

Normally I thought when I do  ORDER BY read_statu ASC it will display the message with the status 0 first and so on and so forth but it does not.

**How to display the messages between those users by ordering in such a way that it will first display messages which  read_statu=0 before displaying those which read_statu are superior to 0 ?**

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that ORDER BY read_status ASC will give you a list ordered by read status, BUT

1. you can not do the ORDER BY before the GROUP BY clause
2. you are using the MAX(id) function, this will return the largest id of the selected group no matter what order you used
3. you are using GROUP BY which will reduce the result to just one entry per user so you will not be able to access ALL last five messages

To actually get the result you want, you could simplify your query in order to display the last five messages giving unread ones precedence:

```
SELECT * FROM mychat_table 
WHERE (`from_id`='$id' OR `to_id`='$id') AND (is_deleted!='$id' AND is_deleted >=0)
ORDER BY read_statu ASC, id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

If you want the result tidy for display you could use this

```
SELECT (IF(`to_id`='$id', `from_id`, `to_id`)) AS contact, message, read_statu 
FROM mychat_table 
WHERE (`from_id`='$id' OR `to_id`='$id') AND (is_deleted!='$id' AND is_deleted >=0)
ORDER BY read_statu ASC, id DESC, contact
LIMIT 5
```

if you need preference to the grouping and not the read_status, then just place contact at the beginning of the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT (IF(`to_id`='$id', `from_id`, `to_id`)) AS contact, message, read_statu 
FROM mychat_table 
WHERE (`from_id`='$id' OR `to_id`='$id') AND (is_deleted!='$id' AND is_deleted >=0)
ORDER BY contact, read_statu ASC, id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

I don't have your data to play around with, so please try the order parameter in different order until you have the desired result, this should get you there.

If you just want to see the last message (preferably unread) from each user (only one message per user) and you can live with just having user id and message text (which should be enough for display) then try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT from_id, (
    SELECT message FROM mychat_table m2 
    WHERE to_id='$id' AND m2.from_id=m1.from_id
    ORDER BY read_statu ASC, id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS message FROM mychat_table m1
WHERE to_id='$id'
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: The first request did not group the result from the chat table by user and by selecting the last message they exchanged. It rather gave me each user with their messages without grouping them. The second request throw an error because there is no field colled mgroup

Comment: `mgroup` in the ORDER BY clause actually was a copy error from my first go on your problem, i corrected it to `contact`. the order of the parameters in the ORDER BY clause can be adapted so they match your needs, as hopefully the third sample does now.

Comment: Still  I am getting the same result even after using the third method. It does not group the result per users but rather list the messages per user

Comment: so what you want is actually the last 5 read messages per user? so it could be 20, 30 or more messages? or you really want to group users, so you only have one message per user? so if you had 5 results, it would be from five different users?

Comment: @hexereisofware I want to group users and take the last message from each users BUT I want them grouped order by  read_statu=0 first and order by read_statu!=0 after. So i need to have only one user with one message (the last message that was sent to the user or that he has sent). So even if a user has sent 10 messages, only the last is shown with the user id . 

Basicaly i am trying to do what facebook does when you want to consult your messages. When you send a message to someone or someone sends a message to you

Comment: @FerdineFaithfull the last sample now gives you a way to retrieve user and last message sent - but it only includes messages received from users